# UPDATE with SELECT with a reference to the updated table

Tags: sql-server

I have a script:

```
UPDATE  a
SET fieldX =
  (SELECT F_Aggregate(x.fieldy)
  FROM  table_B
  INNER JOIN ....
  INNER JOIN ....
  INNER JOIN ....
  ....
  INNER JOIN table_C on .....
  WHERE table_C.fieldY = table_A.fieldY)
FROM table_A a;
```

But now I want to update fieldX only when the select gives a different value. 
Like:

```
UPDATE  a
SET fieldX =
    (SELECT dbo.F_Aggregate(x.fieldy) as result
    FROM  table_B
    INNER JOIN ....
    INNER JOIN ....
    INNER JOIN ....
    ....
    INNER JOIN table_C on .....
    WHERE table_C.fieldY = table_A.fieldY)
FROM table_A a
WHERE fieldX <> result;
```

I have found questions/answers that looks like this but they all have a select statement without a reference to the updated table.
Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: Put it inside the inner select `INNER JOIN table_C on .....
    WHERE table_C.fieldY = table_A.fieldY AND table_A.fieldX <> dbo.F_DoSomeThing(x.fieldy)`

Comment: instead of using subselect - just include table_a in the join statement and update if the values are different. You can update based on joins

Comment: @artm the function can't be in the where clause because its an aggregate function. But if it could, it would still update all rows this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the calculation in other `Data Source` - it could be CTE, table variable or temporary table, etc. Then join the updated table with it:

```
WITH DataSource (fieldY, result)  AS
(
    SELECT table_C.fieldY
          ,dbo.F_Aggregate(x.fieldy) as result
    FROM  table_B
    INNER JOIN ....
    INNER JOIN ....
    INNER JOIN ....
    ....
    INNER JOIN table_C on .....
    GROUP BY table_C.fieldY 

)
UPDATE  table_A
SET fieldX = result
FROM table_A A
INNER JOIN DataSource DS
    ON A.[fieldY] = DS.[fieldY]
WHERE fieldX <> result
```